# why container api launching after the container containing my script

Tags: docker-compose, fastapi

I have a docker compose launching 2 containers. Problem is that it seems that my container with the api that I need to reach from the other container start only after and then I have a request issue.

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  fastapi:
    container_name: my-api
    image: fastapi:latest
    networks:
      - my-network
    ports: 
      - target: 8000
        published: 8000
        mode: host
  authentification:
    container_name: authentification
    networks:
      - my-network
    image: authentification:latest
    volumes:
      - .:/home/log_folder
    depends_on:
      - "fastapi"

networks:
  my-network:
```

Th containers can communicate together as If I launch manually the container with the script `authentification` after the api is started, it works.

Any clue ?

Comment: Have you seen https://docs.docker.com/compose/startup-order/ and the discussion about possible issues?

Comment: yes I have edited my question but I tried with `depend_on` option but did not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dependency checks only container startup, not service. `time.sleep` is a crutch, actually. Just add healthcheck block to your fastapi service

```yaml
fastapi:
  healthcheck:
    test: ["CMD", "curl", "-f", "http://localhost:8000"]
    interval: 1s
    timeout: 2s
    retries: 10
```

and change dependency block to this:

```yaml
authentification:
  depends_on:
    fastapi:
      condition: service_healthy
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally added a `time.sleep` at he beginning of each of my container with script reaching the api to ensure they wait the api is launched. This is not a big issue as these scripts are just test script to check authentification etc ...

Thanks !